# Git rebase starting in interactive 'pick' mode

Tags: git

I was walking through using a standard `git rebase` with a new coworker who had a fairly fresh install of Git, and noticed that when he attempted to begin the rebase, Git notified him that he was running in interactive mode using 'pick'.

When attempting to `--continue` and complete the rebase, it asked for a commit message, which is what we wanted to avoid.

I was able to rebase in standard mode on my own machine without issue. Does anyone know why my coworker's machine is starting in interactive mode, even though he's not using the `-i` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coworker should back out with `git rebase --abort` if there's any doubt of the right thing happening.

As for why Git would enter interactive mode if not asked:

- It's possible that the coworker *did* ask for interactive rebase (though if you were screen sharing one would think you would notice this).
- Check the coworker's config file for the word `rebase` with `interactive` settings (or just `i`), or for some sort of alias that might be messing things up. It is possible to cause the config file to render a rebase interactive by default under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! I had him abort and then I continued on my machine. I did walk him through the process from start to finish over screenshare which is how I know he wasn't asking for an interactive rebase.

Good idea checking for a config file. His config didn't show anything out of the ordinary or anything with the worse rebase in it. (neither globally nor locally to the repo we were working in)

I've asked him to create a new alias that maps to `rebase` and that seemed to resolve our issue. So there appears to have been an override somewhere.

Comment: Well, that sounds like the "some sort of alias" I asked you to look for. I would continue to look for this; it's going to be a problem.